# 3D geometry cube; find a distance

Tags: geometry

Let A1B1C1D1A2B2C2D2 be a cube with A1B1C1D1 being the bottom face and A2B2C2D2 the top face. Given that A1A2 is of length 1 what's the distance between D2A1 and A2B1.

Comment: Is the answer ok?

Answer (score 0):

Big Hint: Pythagoras' Theorem.

Comment: I found out it is sqrt(2)/2 but I am not very sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that you need the distance between the lines $A2B1$ and $D2A1$.
This can be reduced to finding the perpendicular distance between the point A1 and the the mid-point of line $A2B1$.
Let the mid-point of $A2B1$ be $X$
Then the **Distance between the two lines** is $A1X$ which we want to find:
$$(A1X)^2+(B1X)^2=(A1B1)^2    $$
**[Using Pythagoras' Theorem]**
You can find that:
$$B1X={1\over \sqrt{2}}$$
and
$$A1B1=1 $$ 
**Hence** $$A1X={1\over \sqrt{2}}$$